# Testing In App Purchases on TestFlight

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store, testflight

I am trying to test In App Purchases on TestFlight but some things are not clear to me.

I have created my In App Purchase Products and their statuses are 'Ready to Submit'. However at the top on the screen it says "Your first In-App Purchase must be submitted with a new app version. Select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section and click Submit."

So when I click on the 'App Store' tab at the top and then under the 'iOS App' subheading I click '1.0 Prepare for submission'. I am taken to the screen where I fill in the App Store information of the App as if I was going to upload the App to the App Store. There are inputs for me to fill in the description, keywords, screenshots, app icon etc. And I also see the section were I can add some In App Purchases which is what I assume is meant by the previous message "Your first In-App Purchase must be submitted with a new app version. Select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section and click Submit." Here I can select my IAP products for my first submission.

My question is this:

1) I don't want to actually put the app on the App Store yet. I just want to test the IAP on TestFlight with my testers. I assume I need to click the "Manually release this version" radio button when I submit the app for review for this to happen? Or am I meant to do this another way?

2) Since I need to fill in the description, screenshots etc, it sounds like the app basically needs to be completed before I can submit it for review. Could I just add some dummy descriptions and screenshots here? Or does the app really need to be in a close-to-finished state JUST to TEST In-App-Purchases?

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: you have to make sandbox tester account for testing IAP

Comment: You do NOT have to use sandbox test accounts in TestFlight builds. Your testers can stay logged into their real accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing **In-App Purchase** on **TestFlight** you don't need to submit app.
You have to test In-AppPurchase with sandbox account. For in-app purchase from your app you have to logedin with existing id and set your sandbox account in itunes and purchase.

- **Create sandbox Account** (test user for In-App)

**Goto iTunesConnect >> Users and Roles >> Sandbox testers >> add**
give this test accounts credentials to all testers for testing IAP or make many testing account.

> make sure when you have to submit for review please add your in-App
>   purchase with the review (from prepare for submission >> Add In-App
>   purchases).

Comment: So to understand you correctly, you are saying I am able to test IAP in TestFlight EVEN IF the status of my IAP products are "Ready to Submit"?

Comment: @coldbuffet yes i understand that. in testflight testing IAP is always in Ready to Submit

Comment: @coldbuffet havu you any proble with sandbox account?

Comment: @coldbuffet Enjoy. if you stucked any where then ping me any time

Comment: You do NOT have to use sandbox test accounts in TestFlight builds. Your testers can stay logged into their real accounts.

Comment: @Vvk.. My test flight credential and sandbox user is different. When i open app it prompt me for password of test flight user. Not getting any option for give sandbox credential.